# Authentication required?

Tags: discussion, login

When I look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153178/html-colors-margins-rendering-differently-same-code-css-browser), I get some kind of login prompt. Do other people get that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to pictures hosted on a server requiring user name and password.

Going to remove them from the post now.

Comment: I see. Yes, I should have looked at the page source, then I would have spotted that too. I already commented on the question.

Comment: Yep, the OP understood it as well.. messed my edit but oh well. :)

Comment: @MrLister For the record, your browser is not that good to allow mere picture to invoke such dialog. Let me guess.. Internet Explorer?

Comment: SeaMonkey. There's probably some about:config setting to suppress dialogs like those, but then I wouldn't have known that something was amiss!

Comment: Hmm.. so it probably happens with Firefox as well. Surprising!

Comment: By the way, there are situations where this asking for a password would be legit. For instance if you really would want to log in.

Comment: @MrLister of course, when browsing directly to the image URL. But when it's part of `<img>` tag it feels pretty hackish. Chrome silently ignores this and show broken image, like it should be IMO.